# Show Default pop up for accessing the Twitter Account of the user

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, popup

I am using Fabric Framework to login with twitter in my app and using Objective C Lang.

When I am trying to login with twitter then I have set an check which is "If user id and password is not set in the settings account then a pop up will appear which show the message that please set up your account in setting". but when I click the button to login with twitter my dialog box appears before "Default dialog box of the iPhone which ask for accessing the twitter account". So that I am not able to login.
So is there any way to show the default pop up of the iPhone by our self.

Hope it is clear to you!
If any query please write in the comments

Thanks

Comment: What is you current code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried But didn't get anything

Comment: You have to be a bit more descriptive in your question; I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish. A couple of tips: Do a 1.2.3. list of things you want the end user to accomplish, and/or include a screenshot or a diagram of the user flow. What I did not understand about your question: Are you talking about twitter or facebook "popup"? Is the popup an oAuth single-sign-on dialog? Are you using the Facebook iOS SDK? Are you using swift, objective-c, javascript or something else? Are you using Twitter's Fabric library? Even if you have failed, include as much detail as you can.

Comment: Please read the question again I have set it again for you